# How to remove specific page from word document in Aspose Java?

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

How to remove specific page from word document in Aspose Java ?

My requirement is, i have one word document from which i need only first page ?

so either i can remove all the pages except first one or i can create new document read first page from the document and write it to new document.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirements using the "PageSplitter" example project. You can find PageSplitter code in [Aspose.Words for Java examples repository at GitHub](https://github.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-Java/blob/5f6d55dbffc44e33d144525c434c875d75e3d002/Examples/src/main/java/com/aspose/words/examples/loading_saving/PageSplitter.java). Please use following code example to extract the first page from Word document.

```
//Load the document
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

// Create and attach collector to the document before page layout is built.
LayoutCollector layoutCollector = new LayoutCollector(doc);

// Split nodes in the document into separate pages.
DocumentPageSplitter splitter = new DocumentPageSplitter(layoutCollector);

//Get the first page of document
Document newDoc = splitter.GetDocumentOfPage(1);
newDoc.save(MyDir + "Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: That solution is working fine but  i am losing some word document functionality. After splitting i am loosing mail merge fields.

Comment: Please post the issue detail in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) for investigation. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.